# jdbc sqlexception caused by french accent characters

Tags: jdbc, db2, locale, sqlexception

I have a DB2 database configured for french accent characters and via the DB2 command line tool both of the following SQL statements successfully return results containing french accent characters.

```
select * from ca_cpo_inventory where dealer_id = 46170 and locale = 'fr'
```

and

```
select * from ca_cpo_inventory where dealer_id = 46170 and locale = 'en'
```

However in the JEE code the locale = 'fr' SQL works fine via Hibernate and PreparedStatement but the locale = 'en' result in the following exceptions. (note: Exceptions occur only when there are french characters in the English rows. If there are no french characters in result set the SQL works fine).

The same code is used to run both SQL, all that differs is locale.

**When called via Hibernate:**

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [...]; SQL state [null]; error code [-99999]; could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:625)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:95)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:306)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:62)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:212)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:146)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy35.executeFinder(Unknown Source)
at com.mazdausa.persistence.dao.finder.impl.FinderIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
....
Caused by: 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2216)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:66)
at com.mazdausa.persistence.dao.impl.GenericDaoHibernateImpl.executeFinder(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:301)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138)
... 90 more
Caused by: 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.s.a(s.java:1517)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.s.m(s.java:465)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.s.M(s.java:1102)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.lf.getString(lf.java:959)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.lf.getString(lf.java:1290)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getString(WSJdbcResultSet.java:1869)
at org.hibernate.type.StringType.get(StringType.java:18)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2101)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1380)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1308)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1206)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:580)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
...
```

**When called via PreparedStatement:**
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException

Does anyone know have any ideas? Since SQL statements work in DB2 console I am assuming there is no data corruption.

Comment: You should post a longer stack trace, now you are posting the Hibernate exception, where the original `SQLException` is probably more useful.

Comment: I added the stacktrace as written in the log. Unfortunately the entire stack trace isn't logged

Comment: Additional info: If I use SQL with explicit column names in the select and I do not include the columns that contain french accent characters then SQL works and I can select the rows. But if I include the columns that contain french accent characters in the SQL the SQLException occurs. Could it be that I've named my column LOCALE? Could the use of LOCALE = 'en' in my SQL trigger language logic in SQL so when non English characters appear in the results set an exception occurs?

Comment: -99999 means undefined error in the JDBC drivers. According to the IBM there are roughly 2000 different similar errors which are missing the sqlstate (which could tell you the reason). This question lacks information that would probably be required for solving the issue. For instance what is the locale of the database itself? What are all all the connection attributes? What versions (driver+database+spring) are you working with? What db2look gives for ca_cpo_inventory ?